# Exibir dados html do mysql com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Tenho dados em HTML gravados no banco de dados e desejo mostra-los na tela, porém quando mostro esses dados ao invés de formata-los como html, o navegador exibe como um texto as tags e códigos html vindos do banco.

Como faço para exibi-lo sem ser um texto mas sim, formatar como html?

```html
        <!-- Post Content -->
        <section>
          <p><%= row.editor1 %></p>
        </section>
```

Como está exibindo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No print mostrado na pergunta parece não ter nenhum código HTML vindo na variável `row.editor1`. A única tag que tem no print é o `<p>` e ela já está no HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de realizar o que você perguntou seria utilizando a propriedade *Element.**innerHTML***, de acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> A propriedade Element.innerHTML define ou obtém a sintaxe HTML
>   descrevendo os elementos descendentes.

Um exemplo bem simples do uso seria o seguinte:

**Código HTML**

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Exemplo de Alteração de Html usando Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<section id="areaConteudo" name="areaConteudo">

</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Código JavaScript

```
var conteudoHtml="<h1>Conteúdo adicionado pelo JavaScript</h1><br><br><p>Perceba que as tags HTML são corretamente interpretadas</p>";
document.getElementById("areaConteudo").innerHTML=conteudoHtml;
```

Cujo resultado é o seguinte:
[image: Resultado do código do exemplo]

Veja funcionando [no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/netoCosta09/kwq6adz0/).

Basicamente, você está definindo o conteúdo "filho" que será apresentado dentro da section.